# Rails+slimでforを使うと、変な文字列がHTMLに出ます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim

Railsでslimテンプレートを以下のように書いて動かしました。
= for a in 1..3
  = check_box_tag(:aaa)

これを画面で表示するとチェックボックスが3つ表示された後に
1..3
と表示されます。どうもfor a in 1..3の1..3らしいですが。。
なぜでしょう？
<環境>
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
ruby 2.2.3p173
・以下gemsのバージョン
Rails 4.2.5.2
slim-rails 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

単純にRubyで下記のように書いているのと似たようなことです

```
print for a in 1..3
  print a
end
```

結果：

> 1231..3

つまり

`= for a in 1..3`
の`for`の前の `=`が`1..3`を出力してしまっています。

Comment: なるほど。
= xxx
は
print xxx
になるんですね。

なのでこの場合は
= for a in 1..3
ではなく
- for a in 1..3
が正しいと。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: @user3744963 解決してよかったです。厳密には内部処理を追わないとわからないことですので、`同じようなことです`の表現が誤解を生みそうでしたので、`似たようなことです`に編集いたしました。